# ORB_SLAM3 Camera Calibration file

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, robotics, slam

I'm trying to run a a fisheye camera video feed in Monocular ORB_SLAM3 to get a trajectory, but I'm having trouble configuring the proper calibration file for it.

[Fisheye Camera Intrinsicts and Image feed](https://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/fov.html)

Camera Intrinsicts file

```
640 480 -179.471829787234 0 0.002316743975 -3.635968439375e-06 2.0546506810625e-08 320.0 240.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 256.2124 138.2261 -3.8287 23.8296 8.0091 -0.5033 6.7625 4.3653 -1.2425 -1.2663 -0.1870 0.0
```

These are examples of two formats of calibration files for ORB_SLAM3.

https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3/blob/master/Examples_old/Monocular/TUM-VI.yaml

https://github.com/UZ-SLAMLab/ORB_SLAM3/blob/master/Examples_old/Monocular/TUM1.yaml

Any help or guidance would be really appreciated.

I tried usig the distortion parameters and both the camera types but there is something thats wrong, the negative focal length also gives an inverted trajectory but still completely inaccurate.

[Inverted Trajectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i29Nu.png)

[Inaccurate Trajectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKLC9.png)